# printf и write на Си

Tags: c

хочу написать свой `printf` на Си через `write`. В чем ошибка - ничего не выводит

```
void Printf(char *format, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    char *p;
    int *number;
    for(p=format; *p; p++){
        if (*p!='%'){
            putchar(*p);

        }
        else {
            switch (*++p)
            {
            case 'd':
                number = malloc(sizeof(int));
                *number = va_arg(ap, int);
                write(1, number, sizeof(int));
                free(number);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: Выводит, только вы это наверняка не видите. Кстати, примеры входных (и выходных) данных теста весьма приветствуются. Дело в том, что `write()` не делает преобразований двоичного кода чисел в цепочку десятичных цифр в коде ascii, а выводит (в вашем случае 4 байта) как есть.

Comment: Так а что же это вы такое вытворяете? Назначение формата `%d` - выполнять конвертирование внутреннего представления значения типа `int` в строковое представление, т.е. в последовательность ASCII символов. Именно это строковое представление и записывается в стандартный выход в `printf`. А где у вас это конвертирование??? Вы пытаетесь внутреннее представление прямо в бинарном виде пихать в стандартный выход? Разумеется, либо ничего печататься не будет, либо будут печататься кракозябры.

Comment: `write()` — это системный вызов ядра для вывода raw-последовательности байт. Он ничего не знает про форматы чисел. `printf()` — библиотечная функция. Может стоит просто посмотреть в исходные коды *musl* или *uClibc*?